# Can`t remove a new line

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gsub

I have a model, wich has a unique token, to be changed every time the model is saved.

i`m using before_filter to change the token, and it is working, the problem is:

```
class Confirmation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :item_id, :item_type

  before_save :define_token

  def to_param
    token
  end

  private
    def define_token
      str = ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.base64(32).gsub("/","_").gsub(/=+$/,"")
      self.token = Util.secure_hash("#{str} - #{Time.now.utc.to_s} - #{item_id}")
    end
end
```

when i look the token generated it gives me a random string with a \n at the end.

i`ve tried to add this line:

```
def define_token
  str = ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.base64(32).gsub("/","_").gsub(/=+$/,"")
  str = Util.secure_hash("#{str} - #{Time.now.utc.to_s} - #{item_id}")
  self.token = str.gsub("\n", "n")
end
```

but still don`t work, how can i remove the new line at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, assuming the newline is 100% spurious, I would figure out where it is coming from, and remove it there.  But if for some reason that's not an option, the following gsub would work:

```
self.token = str.gsub(/\n$/, "")
```

That will only remove a newline if it's the last entry in the string.  To remove all newlines, use:

```
self.token = str.gsub(/\n/, "")
```

Even easier, the [rstrip](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001191) method will remove trailing whitespace from a string:

```
self.token = str.rstrip
```

Comment: thanks, it magicaly worked, without any changes on the code. thanks anyway